# how can I create a global variable to reset value every time textbox value changes?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a remaining budget value (`txtETLAfterFunding`), which is the
roduct of (`txtELTUnReqdDollars`) - (`txtBudget`). If the `txtETLAfterFunding` is in the negative, I can use `txtAdjustmentAmt` to offset that negative budget.

i.e. `txtETLAfterFunding` = `-$5,000`, so I type in `$5,000` in to the `txtAdjustmentAmt` and the `txtETLAfterFunding` amount is now `$0`. But say I mess up and want to type in `$15,000` in `txtAdjustmentAmt`. Now the remaining budget balance adds that to the $0 from the last calc, where I want it to reset back to `-$5,000` so that I can then add `$15,000` to that and make the remaining budget at $10,000.

I know I need to put my `txtELTAfterFunding` as a global variable in order to have it reset, but I am lost on how to do that.

code:

```
Private Sub txtAdjustmentAmt_AfterUpdate()
    If optReduceReq = True Then
        txtELTAfterFunding.Value = CDbl(txtAdjustmentAmt.Value) + CDbl(txtELTAfterFunding.Value)
    End If
txtELTAfterFunding.Value = Format(txtELTAfterFunding, "$#,##.00")
End Sub
```

Comment: AFAIK It's strongly suggested against using global variables [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/485020/1521579). As an alternative you could store values in a cell, in the registry. If you decide to go the global variable path, [read this](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/userforms-a-few-questions-on-variable-scope.456670/post-2255047)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just set txtETLAfterFunding to be calculated as

```
txtETLAfterFunding = txtELTUnReqdDollars - txtBudget + txtAdjustmentAmt
```

You would then put the calculation into e.g. "Private Sub ReCalc", which you can call from the _AfterUpdate of the 3 textboxes.

As an aside, your Format code should probably read Format(txtELTAfterFunding, "$#,##0.00").

Comment: wow, such a simple solution. Appreciate your help!